# Can I use ember.js with jquery-ui accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js

I have a template that iterates over a controller array - and for some reason i can't use the jquery-ui accordion function - I think that this is due to the added markup ember adds to the html e.g. `<script type="text/x-placeholder" id="metamorph-1-start"></script>`

Any thoughts how can i fix this?

here is the code:

```
<div id="chat-tab-container">

                <script type="text/x-handlebars">
                    {{#each App.chatTabsController}} 

                        <h3 class="row1">
                            <div class="avatar " style="background: red;">*</div>
                            <div class="contact-name ">{{contactName}}</div>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="row2">
                            <div class="contact-name ">content</div>
                        </div>

                        <h3 class="row1">
                            <div class="avatar " style="background: red;">*</div>
                            <div class="contact-name ">boni</div>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="row2">
                            <div class="contact-name ">content</div>
                        </div>

                    {{/each}}
                </script>

            </div>
```

and the jquery call: `$('#chat-tab-container').accordion()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cory mentioned the problem is that the content for the accordion is not rendered/inserted in the DOM when you call the accordion method. One workaround is that you use a ember view as a wrapper and call the accordion method inside the didInsertElement method. I have provided a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manuel_mitasch/CccKP/) with a working example.

Basically your template changes to:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view App.TabView}}                     
    {{#each App.chatTabsController.content}} 
      <h3>{{contactName}}</h3>
      <div>content for {{contactName}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

​
Code for view:

```
App.TabView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',        
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().accordion();
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks!!!
another option that worked for me is explicitly setting the handle option of the accordion to 'h3': `$('#chat-tab-container').accordion({handle: 'h3'})`

Comment: The issue I often run into with this method is that if App.chatTabsController.content is an ArrayController (which in this example I think it is) and I push additional content on App.chatTabsController.content things may not act as expected. With the accordion view this may not be an issue because I'd assume in most situations the content is pretty static, but with other jQuery widgets like draggables new content on the array will render, but the dom element may not have the required jQuery attributes to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as I am using it in a project without issue. Have you tried calling $('#chat-tab-container').accordion() from the console once the page is fully loaded? More often than not the issue with jQuery widgets arises from the fact that the content is not rendered or gets re-rendered when the content controller changes.

This can be overcome a few ways:

1. Use an Ember.View and hook into didInsertElement or afterRender callbacks.
2. If you're views update a lot because of content changes you can add an event listener to call $('#chat-tab-container').accordion() when the mouse enters the widget UI area. I use this approach a lot for sortables, accordions, and draggables.

Below is an example:

```
$('body').on( 'mouseover', '#chat-tab-container', function(){
  $(this). accordion();
});
```

Comment: nice idea. Just I think better to use jQuery's method `one`.